# How linear regression treats X and Y data from csv file

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I trained a model and got 92% accuracy. But I am not sure if it is what I am looking for. Because I have two csv files I used one of them as X and one as Y. They have these shapes X=(207399, 25), Y=(207399, 85). What I wanted to achieve here was to predict Y(output) by using X(input). But I wanted the model to find a relation by comparing the input's first row with the output's first row. Accordingly, second to second, third to third etc. By accuracy score, I'm expecting that model predicts for example X(7,:) --> Y(7,:), X(8,:) --> Y(8,:)... etc.

(: means all columns).

Is that what I achieved by Linear Regression in Python? Or should I specify how the model should treat data?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, a linear regression with two input variables and one output variable is the following

```
a_1 * x_1 + a_2 * x_2 = y
```

What it does is try to find an a_1 and a_2 that minimizes the error. In your file, if what you're trying to do is look at how predictive x_1 is of y_1, and you're not really looking for x_1, x_2, ...x_n together predict y_1, then what you're really looking for is the correlation. There are functions built into numpy or scipy that will give you pairwise correlations.

Comment: Do you mean it uses all the 207399 lines to just predict y_1? instead of all 207399 Y? What happens to the rest of Y then?